# How to query from Bigquery on clustering table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-bigquery

I have a clustered table on big query and I am trying to query data from it using "LINQ-to-BigQuery" library and here is my .Net code:

```
 var result = context.From<Data>()
               .Where(x => x.First_Name.Contains("Mahmmod"))
               .Select()
               .Limit(10)
               .Run();
```

After running this code I receive

> Google.GoogleApiException: 'Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError Querying
> tables with clustering is not supported in Legacy SQL

Anyone have a solution for this problem or other library to to query from the bigQuery as linq not SQL statements.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with either C# or LINQ, but the error you get is because BigQuery receives a Legacy SQL query, and not a Standard SQL query.

However, clustered tables cannot be queried with Legacy SQL (cf [this doc page](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-clustered-tables)).

In order to solve your issue you should ensure that what BigQuery receives is Standard SQL. In most client libraries it's about passing a parameter legacy_sql = False, however if [this](https://github.com/neuecc/LINQ-to-BigQuery) is the library you're using I didn't find that option (in addition it is not maintained anymore with a last release dating back from 2016).

Perhaps your best solution is to change client libraries. Google recommends Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2 in the case of C# (see [this quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-client-libraries)).

Comment: First thanks for your reply,

the problem that I want to use any library to facilitate writing complex SQL statements as a LINQ to avoid writing it as string statement.